# Error converting igraph to network object in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am attempting to convert an igraph object to a network object in R. I gather this conversion can be achieved using the asNetwork function from the intergraph package. However, this results in an error. I get the same error whether I use an igraph object that I generated myself, or an example igraph object from the intergraph package, or these igraph objects converted to data frames containing details of the edges and vertices.

For example, `exIgraph` is an example igraph object from intergraph. Using `asNetwork(exIgraph)` produces the error:

```
> exIgraph
IGRAPH 3625f1a D--- 15 11 -- 
+ attr: label (v/c), label (e/c)
+ edges from 3625f1a:
 [1]  2-> 1  3-> 1  4-> 1  5-> 1  6-> 7  8-> 9 10->11 11->12 12->13 13->14 14->12

> asNetwork(exIgraph)    
Error in .Call(setVertexAttribute_R, x, attrname, value, v) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

Converting the igraph object to data frames works, but then converting the data frames to a network gives the same error:

```
> l <- asDF(exIgraph) # this works
> asNetwork(l$edges, vertices=l$vertexes)
Error in .Call(setVertexAttribute_R, x, attrname, value, v) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

I also get a related error in slightly different circumstances. `exNetwork` is an example network object from intergraph. Entering `exNetwork` results in the following:

```
> exNetwork
 Network attributes:
  vertices = 15 
  directed = TRUE 
  hyper = FALSE 
  loops = FALSE 
  multiple = FALSE 
  bipartite = FALSE 
Error in .Call(networkEdgecount_R, x, na.omit) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

What do these errors mean, and how can I fix it?

(I am using R 3.5.1 in RStudio 1.1.463)

Comment: I am using R 3.5.2  and I do not get either of these errors. Also,     intergraph_2.0-2;  igraph_1.2.4; network_1.13.0.1

Comment: Thanks for that. I updated to R 3.5.2, intergraph_2.0-2, igraph_1.2.4, network_1.13.0.1, and that seems to have resolved the problem.